# PHP Unable to initialise Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

We have a custom compiled php (5.6.32) that we want to get working with mysqli. We did have an old compiled version (5.3.10) that worked ok.

We have an old mysqli.so in

```
/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so
```

We are compiling php with

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql --with-zlib --with-libdir=lib64 --with-openssl --with-curl --enable-soap --with-mysqli
```

I have also tried

```
--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config
```

It confirms

```
checking for MySQLi support... yes
```

However when we try and run a php we get the error...

```
HP Warning:  PHP Startup: mysqli: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20131226
```

My guess is it's because there is an old mysqli.so file still there from a previous compile ?

No matter what we try and do, a new mysqli.so file isn't created anywhere.

Should a php compile create mysqli.so ? (if not how do we recreate it). Or any other ideas about how to fix the problem ?

config.nice shows

```
'./configure' \
'--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs' \
'--with-mysql' \
'--with-zlib' \
'--with-libdir=lib64' \
'--with-openssl' \
'--with-curl' \
'--enable-soap' \
'--with-mysqli' \
"$@"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this error may be a red herring actually, I am still testing. Mysqli seems to be working, just that error appears at first.

So is it possible mysqli is somehow built into the binary now, and mysqli is not needed ?

So I have simply commented out mysqli.so in the php.ini file. So that error no longer happens (as I assume it's not trying to load an old .so lib in).

I am still confused as to how mysqli now works though, so if anyone has a better answer, I will gladly accept.